# Best approach to color objects in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I' doing a BIM project using autodesk forge viewer ( I'm using viewer version 6*).

I want color different objects in different color according to the completion status .

Check the below image .

Objects are already colored I tried using setThemingColor but it does not work. I do not want to use setSelectionColor since my object is to show the color without selecting a specific object.

ex: in the below image, i want to color circled objects with the respective color.

[sample_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oliun.jpg)

update :

here is the code snippet I'm using

```
function changeObjectColor(modelId, status){
 
  var color ;
  switch (status) {
    case 'Green':
      color =  new THREE.Vector4(0, 0.5, 0, 0.5);
      break;
    case 'Red':
      color =  new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0.5);
      break;
  }

  viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().setThemingColor(modelId,color);
}
```

the result
[result after setting the color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvmAP.jpg)

i also use isolate and select methods as well , but even after removing those two method calls still the color won't change for a specific object

new try outs :

So i managed to set/hide object texture  ( just gray color) following this [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/showhide-textures-object-forge-viewer). But then I tried using the setThemingColor method but still the objects wont show the expected color

```
  viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().setThemingColor(modelId, color, null, true);
  viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().impl.invalidate(true, true, false);
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [setThemingColor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive) method is available in v6 and should be working fine. Consider posting the snippet of your code that's responsible for setting the color.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-digital-twin/blob/master/public/scripts/extensions/heatmap.js#L74) of how the method is used in the [Forge Digital Twin](https://forge-digital-twin.autodesk.io) demo.

Comment: Hello Petr, i updated the post with my code , i will go through the example thanks

Comment: Thanks! Please note that if you're coloring an object ID that is not a leaf node (in other words, the object with this ID is made of multiple objects), you will want to set the 4th parameter of the `setThemingColor` method to `true` to apply the colors recursively.

Comment: I used 

  viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().setThemingColor(modelId, color, null, true);



but the result is the same for me

Comment: Not sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947925/changing-materials-in-forge) might help?